# How to render different template for some tabs in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a tab content template set to my tab control:

```
<TabControl         SelectedIndex="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AppTabItemTemplate}"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AppTabContentTemplate}" />
```

The thing is that most of the times the current template is wanted, but there are times when I want to display another template instead. The item source provides this data whether it should show one or another, but how can I do an "if" in XAML and use an alternative UI when the other layout is wanted?

Should this logic be part of the template or the containing XAML that includes this tab control? The information that is used to make the decision between UIs is in the item source.

Comment: [`ItemTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).

You will need to define your selection logic in a class that derives DataTemplateSelector, create a resource for your selector in XAML and then use it by assigning the resource to the ItemTemplateSelector property of your tab control.